# Adding dropdown to Li nav html

Tags: html, css

so I have this:

```
<ul class="nav-menu list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#header" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

it's as simple as it gets. But what I want to do is add a hoverable dropdown to the `about` `<li>` tag, so i can have options such as Team, etc.

i tried to add things such as an `<li>` with an `<li>`, but that didn't work. and i also tried researching how to add it in, but cannot find it for my example:

```
<ul class="nav-menu list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#header" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll">Services</a>
 <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I have never done this before, and am a little bit inexperienced in this section, so I am hoping someone can help me!
Thanks:)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. It is expected that you have done sufficient research efford and tried to solve an issue on your own. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? what is not working as expected?

Comment: hi! thanks for the reply. i just edited my question to show what i've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an `<li>` inside another `<li>` won't work without starting a new ordered or unordered list inside the list-item.

What you're looking for, can be done using CSS. You can hide the dropdown-content and only display it on-hover, using the `:hover`-pseudo class. Here's an example:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I tried integrating this with my navbar, and it is so close, but the `about` word is lower then the other words, and i can't figure it out . please take a look, sorry it is lots of css. but here's what i have https://codepen.io/gianlucaas/pen/dyWwjwq?editors=1100

Comment: This is because the line-height is different. You've specified 32 px in `.nav-menu`. For analysing your site, you can always bring up the inspector using F12 or ⌘⌥C, if you're on a Mac :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get it done is to create a div to contain the sub list inside the `<li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>` so it will be like this.

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">team</a>
    <a href="#">other member</a>
    <a href="#">etc.</a>
  </div>
 </li>
```

I give the li a class of dropdown and create a div with a class of dropdown-content, add the list of sub-list you want inside the about and now you need to hide the display of the `dropdown-content` by using CSS code `display: none;`
and make the display of `a` tags inside `dropdown-content` `display: block;`

at last all you need to do now is make `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}`

and sorry for making the answer this long, hope will answer your question.